# mysql_insert_id return 0 even after a successful insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have made sure the id in table1 is primary and auto-incrementing. Even the insert is happening successfully. However, in table2 id is 0. Also, mysqli_real_escape_string is not working with $_POST['xyz1'] in this case.

```
<?php
include ('db.php');
session_start();

$q1="insert into xyz (email, content) values          ('".$_SESSION['Email']."','".$_POST['xyz1']."')";
$query1=mysqli_query($pqr,$q1);
$a=mysqli_insert_id();

$q2="insert into xyz2 (email,content2,id) values ('".$_SESSION['Email']."','".$_POST['xyz3']."', '".$a."')";
$query2=mysqli_query($pqr,$q2);



echo "done";
?>
```

Comment: do you have an autoincrement id?

Comment: yes(in xyz). id in xyz2 is not auto incremented.

Comment: can anyone suggest what to edit in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously need the [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) function of mysqli, you missed the `i`.

Also: Switch to Prepared Statements, instead of using `mysqli_real_escape_string`. They are far superior.

Comment: mysqli_insert_id is still returning 0.can you suggest something else for the id. With last_insert_id, it was working fine but I cant use that.

Comment: @user3452721 Did you provide the proper connection?

Comment: yes, the content is getting successfully added. so the connection must be proper.

Comment: @user3452721 That wasn't my question: Did you specify the correct connection as the first parameter of `mysqli_insert_id`?

Comment: one more thing,if I have another auto increment id in table2, will using mysqli_insert_id return that or the former one?